# deriving equations for point clouds in sympy or alternatives

Tags: python, geometry, sympy, analytical

Assume you have a point cloud (stored in `R`, 3xN dimensional matrix) in a 3D orthogonal coordinate system,
and you would like to derive analytical expressions for complicated functions of R (including differentiation, summations, etc.

As a simple example:

```
A_il(R)=\sum_jk df(R)/dR_ij  df(R)/dR_kl
```

Is there any way to do this in sympy (or anything else...) with eg generalizing `x,y,z` to `X={x_i}, Y={y_i}, Z={z_i}`?

I would like to obtain general expression with Dirac deltas so that I do not need to handle all options separately. If it is an option I would prefer Einstein notation.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I think that you need to break this down and start with a simpler question.

Comment: OK, let's start with this can we define a vector of variables X={x_i}, such that it provides the property:
Deriv[X,x_k]={DiracDelta(i,k)}

Comment: sorry, I meant
Deriv[X,x_k]={KroneckerDelta[i,k]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to your comment here. Maybe this does what you want:

```py
In [12]: X = IndexedBase('X')                                                                                                                  

In [13]: i, j = symbols('i, j')                                                                                                                

In [14]: X[i].diff(X[j])                                                                                                                       
Out[14]: 
δ   
 i,j
```